# How can you put a space at the start of every line?

Tags: vb.net, textbox

Simple question, i have a textbox which may be multilined (it might not be depending on  user input) and is referred to as i:

```
dim i as string
i = textbox1.text
```

I need to insert a space at the start of every line in i. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Add a space to the first line manually, and replace all new lines by a new line followed by a space:

```
i = " " & Replace(textbox1.text, Chr$(10), Chr$(10) & " ")
```

Comment: i pasted this code in and it came up with an error: "Type character '$' does not match declared data type 'Char'"

Answer (score 1):

```
i = " " + replace( trim(textbox1.text), vbCrLf, " " + vbCrLf)
```

1. start with space
2. trim the textbox1 in order to get rid of leading space(s) (i presume u want 1)
3. replace the CR/LF's with space + CR LF